# Facebook login page and cache

Tags: mysql, facebook, caching, logging, cookies

I've got a Facebook login in my website
but I need to request permission to post in my user's wall.

I found many many examples on google that use the scope, but they're too different form mine, and I don't understand where to put it

This is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
// added in v4.0.0
require_once 'autoload.php';
require 'functions.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'APPID','APPSECURE' );
// login helper with redirect_uri
    $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://www.bestparty.altervista.org/APP/facebook/fbconfig.php' );
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
        $fbid = $graphObject->getProperty('id');              // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbfullname = $graphObject->getProperty('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $graphObject->getProperty('email');   
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
         checkuser($fbid,$fbfullname,$femail);
    /* ---- header location after session ----*/


        $cookie_name = 'FBID';
        $cookie_value = $fbid;
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); 
        $cookie_name2 = 'FULLNAME';
        $cookie_value2 = $fbfullname;
        setcookie($cookie_name2, $cookie_value2, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); 

  header("Location: ../gestaccount.php");
} else {

  $cookie_name = 'FBID';
        $cookie_value = $fbid;
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); 
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

Also:

1. May I save the access token in mysql to use it in future?
2. Why does the datas that I save in cache stays only until I close the browser?

Answer (score 0):

1, You can store the access token however which way you like. As long as it's secure and you are able to update them in case of expired/updated/extended access tokens, it should be fine.
2, This is a bit unclear, are you setting and handling cookies correctly ?